# Why does this CSS Attribute selector not work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<style>
div [data-endpoint="/one/two/three/"] {display:none}
</style>

<div data-endpoint="/one/two/three/">
    example text
</div>
```

live code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DDUNp/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the space between the `div` and the `data-endpoint` attribute explicitly specifies that the element with that attribute is a descendant element of the `div`; remove the space and it works:

```
div[data-endpoint="/one/two/three/"] {display:none}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DDUNp/3/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 3):

There's a whitespace to much:

```
div[data-endpoint="/one/two/three/"] {display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between div and [

```
div[data-endpoint="/one/two/three/"] {display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between div and [data-endpoint="/one/two/three/"]

Answer (score 0):

Is working. Just remove the space.

http://jsfiddle.net/DDUNp/4/

```
div[data-endpoint='/one/two/three/'] {display:none;}
```

Comment: Ummm, it's not working if you have to change it in order to make it work.

Comment: @BoltClock will make sure my comments are proper. Tks for highlighting.